# Not able to configure run path for web application project in Eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, web

I am using Eclipse for Java EE and Tomcat Server 7.0. I created two projects in my workspace - a core Java and a web project.

I have the core Java project added to the build path of web project and this allows for the compilation of the web project, error free. But my problem is that at run-time the web project is not referring to or picking up the Java files from the core Java project.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export your core Java project to a jar file from eclipse & add this jar file to your classpath. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: If we add as a jar it works. But i am currently developing both the web and java application project. Every time i need to export as a jar to make it work. Is there any other way to do this,..

Comment: It should get resolved if you are exporting your web application to a ".war" file along with the jar dependencies while deploying to Tomcat.

Comment: It is working, But i am asking is there any other solution apart from this.