# Eclipse - Make dynamic web application include other projects in workspace

Tags: eclipse

I'd like the exported .war file to include the other (referenced) projects in the workspace.

When I reference them in the Build Path only, it shows no "Problems", but  ClassNotFoundException is thrown later, when I try to "Run on Server" or export.

Using eclipse Kepler, tomcat 7.0.42.

I've seen the solution here: [Not able to configure run path for web application project in Eclipse workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542861/not-able-to-configure-run-path-for-web-application-project-in-eclipse-workspace); that's how it works now. Is there a more convenient way?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Tomcat within Eclipse?  Try this:

1. `Run` -> `Run Configurations...` (or `Debug Configurations...`).
2. Find `Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost` (or whatever it's named for you) under `Apache Tomcat` on the left-hand side.
3. Go to the `Classpath` tab on the right.
4. Select `User Entries` and click `Add Projects...`.
5. Select the projects you wish to include.

That should place that project on Tomcat's classpath.